# Android animation alpha from the center to the edges

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I want to show alpha animation that reduces transparency from center ImageView to the border.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with this library: https://github.com/kyze8439690/RevealLayout